# What does it mean when there's a minus sign in front of a signal?

Tags: verilog

What does it mean when there's a minus sign in front of a signal?

For example:

```
reg [8:0] A;
reg [4:0] B;
wire C;
assign C = -A[4:0] <= B;
```

What's the meaning of the `-A[4:0]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unary minus operator `-` produces the 2-complement of the operand. That complements each bit and adds 1 to the result. If A[4:0]=5'b00011, then `-A[4:0]` would be 5'b11101.

Note that the operand gets extended to the width based on the context of the expression it's in *before* the `-` operator gets applied. If you had declared `reg [8:0] B;`, then `-A[4:0]` in your example would result in 9'b111111101.